# record video in cocos2d iOS game, low resolution for video and high resolution for normal cases

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I am using cocos2d's CCRenderTexture to record video of my game. But if recording video in retina display resolution will cost lot of CPU and memory, so I want to use low resolution for video record but keep retina-resolution for normal game play. is it possible?

I've tried  "[[CCDirector sharedDirector] enableRetinaDisplay:NO];" during record video, but it seems not work. the generated output totally wrong.

Comment: are you trying for a way to record your game's gameplay video?

Comment: @BijoyThangaraj I want the "talking tom" style video record inside my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is not feasible.**

You'd have to render each frame twice, once on the screen, then onto the render texture. A serious drop in framerate is inevitable even if you lower the resolution of the render texture somehow.

The reason is simply that you'll also have to write each render texture as an image to flash memory. This is extremely slow. You'll also end up with a huge amount of data. If each (PNG/JPG) image file ends up being a reasonably small 50 KB then one second of recorded data at 60 fps will consume 3 Megabytes of flash memory. One minute would be around 180 Megabytes.

To record a demo of your game, most games follow the simple principle of recording the user input, and then playing back the user input as if the user had issued these commands. This requires careful planning, no breaking changes when updating the app (or invalidating old demos), and no use of non-deterministic randomizers (ie seeded with time).

If you need to record a demo for making a trailer video, there's plenty of screengrabbing solutions around. Some even specialize in grabbing iPhone video, either from the device (usually requires a source code/library component) or from the Simulator.

Comment: This is actually incorrect, and the recording can be done. Check out https://everyplay.com/ for more info. The videos on the page are recorded from the device, while the user plays them, without visible performance loss.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out Kamcord SDK for recording game play. Check at http://kamcord.com/

Kamcord has a built-in gameplay video and audio recording technology for iOS. It allows you, the game developer, to capture gameplay videos with an API. Your users can then replay and share these gameplay videos via YouTube, Facebook, Twitter, and email.

Comment: Yes, actually I've investigated Kamcord. It include a modified cocos2d, but not open source so it cannot be modified. My project requires some  modification of cocos2d, thus Kamcord is not a option for me.

Comment: It is not a modified version of cocos2d but actually uses cocos2d. It just has extended the CCGLView class of cocos2d. So it should not be a problem for you.

Comment: If Kamcord does not provide the necessary functionality, please checkout Everyplay (https://developers.everyplay.com/). We provide a OpenGL-level API for recording gameplay, which you could use if the provided cocos integration does not do what you want.